# How do I add an overlay to these divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a [JSFiddle to show](https://jsfiddle.net/marcamillion/n0dxkae4/1/) what the interface looks like.

What I want to do is, on the some of the `div.contact-box` elements, I would like to apply a CSS overlay to some of them....where there is a black overlay (say with 70% opacity) over all of the content within the `contact-box`.

<s>On that overlay, I want to add a regular Bootstrap button with a `p` tag and some language above the button (like `Click here to unlock this profile`).</s>

When the user hovers on that overlay, I want to show a regular Bootstrap button with a `p` tag and some language above the button (like `Click here to unlock this profile`).

Because SO requires some code, this is what the CSS for the `div.contact-box` looks like:

```
.contact-box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

All of the `.contact-box` styles are at the bottom of the CSS in the fiddle.

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

Ideally it should be a new class that I can add & remove to the `div.contact-box` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about giving `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the `.well`?

I added the following **CSS**:

```css
.hidden-profile {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hidden-profile > * {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.hidden-profile .well {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.hidden-profile .well p {
  margin: 0;
}
.hidden-profile:hover .well {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And this **HTML**:

```
<div class="contact-box profile-38 hidden-profile">
  <div class="well">
    <p>Unlock to view!</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Rest of the Code.. -->
</div>
```

**Preview**

Normal State:

[image: preview]

Hovered State:

[image: preview]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
body {
  background: #2f4050;
}
.players {
  margin: 25px;
}
.players li {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 7em;
}
.players li span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}
.players li.hidden-profile {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.players li.hidden-profile p {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="players">
  <li><span>Player Stuff</span></li>
  <li class="hidden-profile">
    <p>Hello, this is hidden.</p><span>Player Stuff</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>Player Stuff</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Preview**

[image: preveiw]